# Using gnome-open to open pdf files

Tags: latex, default-programs, gnome-open

I configured evince to be my default application to open pdf files (using Open with... and clicking on always opening pdf files with this application), but when I type `gnome-open foo.pdf` instead of evince, I have Nautilus that opens up in the correct folder highlighting the file of my choice.

This is especially disturbing since I am using the LaTeX plugin for gedit, and when I try and compile a tex file to pdf, instead of opening up a new window with my compiled pdf file, I just have nautilus pop-up.
I know I can edit the scripts of my gedit LaTeX plugin to call on evince (or acroread) with the pdf I want opened, but this is a workaround and not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `xdg-open`?

Comment: @dv3500ea Yes. Exact same problem with xdg-open. BTW. what is `xdg-open`? Never heard of it.

Comment: @This is still driving me crazy, so bounty it is...

Comment: I think you might be encountering a bug, I'm getting something similar with Nautilus showing up in the open-with list for files when it shouldn't, so it's likely a bug in Natty somewhere.

Comment: guessing the issue arose from installing rabbitvcs-thunar as per http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu

Comment: @S.B: xdg-open is (or should be) the "standard" way of opening files in a distro-agnostic way. It handles all the hassle of finding out which distro/desktop you are using (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, etc), and launches the files using the proper command. In a Gnome enviroment, xdg-open ends up using the modern `gvfs-open`, while `gnome-open` is used as a fallback if gvfs-open is not found. Its **strongly** recomended that you use xdg-open instead of gnome-open, so your scripts/apps/whatever will be much more portable (and future-proof)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removing `exo-utils` worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Oh, hutch, this worked! Thanks!! I feel bad that the bounty time is over, as you full deserve the points... I only tried your solution now. Don't know why I had exo-utils installed in the first place. Thanks again!!

Comment: I just hit the same problem (where gnome-open and xdg-open could not open anything than directories), and this helped (it removed the whole xubuntu-desktop stuff).

Comment: but that would remove xfce :(

Comment: It can be fixed without removing exo-utils/xfce: http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169

Comment: This fix also works for `gvfs-open` misbehaving on Fedora with MATE. The package name on Fedora is `exo`. You may have installed it by accident with `xfburn`.

Answer (score 8):

**Forth Approach**

I could reproduce your problem by deleting this file `/usr/share/applications/evince.desktop`, so make sure you have this file.

[Reference](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38827).

**Third Approach**

xdg-open appears to use the configuration of `/etc/mailcap`. So edit it to associate pdf with evince.

```
gksu gedit /etc/mailcap
```

Look for the lines that begin with `application/pdf`; `application/x-pdf`; `application/x-bzpdf`; `application/x-gzpdf`. They should look like this to associate pdf with evince:

```
application/pdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-pdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-bzpdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf.bz2
application/x-gzpdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf.gz
```

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1075908.html%27).

**Second Approach**

What is the output of

```
xdg-mime query filetype foo.pdf
```

If the output isn't what we should expect, then:

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

[Reference](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html).

**First Approach**

There are other places that the file associations are set.

You may change the files associations at:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list 
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/  
~/.gnome/share/apps/
```

Look for "pdf" and for "Nautilus" inside theses files.

Comment: thanks for all the info, but unfortunately this doesn't help (or at least I couldn't do anything useful with it). Here are my findings:

/usr/share/applications/defaults.list has acroread as my preferred PDF application (changed it from evince)

/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache has all the list of applications that can open PDF files. Nautilus is not listed as one of them

~/.local/share/applications/ had a file names mimeinfo.cache but had no PDF there (maybe I should add it manually??)

And lastly, I don't have a directory named ~/.gnome.

Comment: @dasgua, thanks for looking into this. Tried `gvfs-open` and got the same result (i.e. Nautilus opens up). See above that I also tried `xdg-open`, and nothing changed. First of all, why are there so many `foo-open` options? Second, the `gvfs-option` not only did not work, it also made my machine log off... Don't know if it's the `gvfs-option` fault though, since the same thing happened to me earlier today with google-chrome. I think there's a bug with unity (or compiz) that makes you session self-destroy...

Comment: thanks for sticking with me... tried the second approach. Typing the first command simply returned `application/pdf` as I wasn't sure if this was "what I should expect" I ran the second command (which should read) `xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf` (it wouldn't let run it the way you referred to it) and still the same thing. Nautilus just opens up... frustrating

Comment: thanks for all your effort! Unfortunately... I do have evince.desktop. BTW, setting adobe reader as my default pdf reader also produces the same output, so I was skeptic of this solution from the beginning... :-)

Comment: It is my hobby find solutions for software ;-). If you login as another user, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem today, and according to this thread on ubuntuforums.org, it's caused by exo-utils:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1729680

exo-tools is a dependency of Thunar (which I installed today), but isn't normally installed in stock Ubuntu, which I guess is why they missed this bug in release.

Removing this packaged (I actually just removed Thunar and all it's deps) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: No need to remove it! See my answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169

Answer (score 4):

The problem is related to `exo-utils`.

1. there is a bug, which has been fixed for Ubuntu Utopic: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/956255
2. for some reason, the following `x-scheme-handler` lines got copied/sticked in ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

```
    % grep exo ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list 
    x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop
    x-scheme-handler/trash=exo-file-manager.desktop
```

This caused `xdg-open`/`gvfs-open` to use `/usr/share/applications/exo-file-manager.desktop`, which contains:

```
Exec=exo-open --launch FileManager %u
```

This is the reason that even with the fixed package, it still opened Nautilus for every file.

Comment: Obvious note that to fix this, you need to remove those lines from the `mimeapps.list` file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from `thunar` and `exo-utils` (which is needed by `thunar`). Removing them solves the problem.

Comment: No need to remove it. See http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, removing exo-utils did not work for me.

After a little digging I found two entries for application/pdf in /etc/mailcap that were prioritizing Xpdf over evince.

After commenting out the two entries for Xpdf, xdg-open correctly opens pdf documents with evince.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing nautilus to manage my files under Xubuntu 11.10. When I moved back to plain Ubuntu 12.04 the problem was there too.

Simple solution if this happens **ONLY to your user** (close to what desgua already said): **delete `~/.local/share/application`s directory** and everything should go back to normal. You may want to backup some shortcuts inside that directory if you want to preserve them.

Comment: You need to only remove exo-related lines from `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, see http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169.

Answer (score -1):

Working fine for me, gnome-open opens up Adobe Reader properly.
Could you try with Adobe reader once.

Might be the case that evince is not properly set as default somewhere.

I am using Natty BTW.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that. No matter what is set as default, I still get Nautilus to open up.