# xdg-open file.cbz opens nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, xdg-open

I'm using Calibre and it seems that it uses `xdg-open` to open files. This, even when tried in terminal, only opens nautilus and the file is selected, but not opened. It doesn't matter if I try to open `.cbz` or `.pdf`.

This seems fine: `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

```
application/x-cbr=evince.desktop
application/x-cbz=evince.desktop
```

Sure when I open the file in Nautilus it opens, but this approach is quite annoying.

Comment: I tried 'xdg-open Horses.pdf' in oneiric and it opens in evince.

Comment: Could you post the file (or a similar file)? What does it look like when it "opens in nautilus" (screenshot)? Are you sure it's not opening in Evince? Please edit your post with the details.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the file is, even .jpg's open nautilus. I'm very sure that it is Nautilus (3.2.1) as it says so in the about-box. Screenshots won't do any good since there really is nothing to see. The terminal command gives no error, but launches Nautilus, with the file selected (as in single-clicked).

Comment: I started having this problem when I installed xubuntu-desktop alongside gnome. (`exo-open` works, but `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` always open nautilus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to the same problem in an answer for another askubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/a/39602/1943

Basically you have to set Thunar as default file manager for `xfce`:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10884462&postcount=16

Once you do that, `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` will avoid using `exo-helper` to open nautilus. Somehow gnome and xfce get interwoven.

EDIT: the downside is that now Thunar opens instead of nautilus when opening folders.
But I find it less frustrating, on the other hand I could uninstall xfce4 if I really don't want it

Comment: That works, thanks.
short form to help others:

- open 'exo-preferred-applications'
- change the preferred "file manager" under "utilities" to Thunar"

Comment: This bug persists even in 12.04. Is there a bug filed in Launchpad?

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Bug #751374 “Dash won't open files anymore” : Bugs : “unity-place-files” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374)

See [comment #27](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374/comments/22) in the source thread. I modified the original commands to use `sed`.

1. Remove mime entries containing exo as a normal user.

   `sed -i '/exo/d' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
2. Update mime desktop database.

   `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications`

This helped me fix my own Ubuntu/XFCE install without removing XFCE.  You may have to modify more (see source thread), but these commands fixed it in my install.

From what I gather in the source thread, the bug may have been fixed for clean installs.

Comment: @NoBugs See the source thread in my answer for the relevant bug on Launchpad.