# In Unity, the folder containing a file selected in the dash is opened in Nautilus instead of opening the file with the corresponding application

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, unity-dash, xfce, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Files lens and xdg-open only open nautilus but not the correct applicatiion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53225/files-lens-and-xdg-open-only-open-nautilus-but-not-the-correct-applicatiion)

In 12.04, since yesterday the behavior of the dash in Unity has changed.

Previously (and I assume it is the default choice), when selecting a file in the dash, the file was automatically opened with its corresponding application. Now, the folder containing the file is opened in Nautilus instead.

(I have to mention that I have installed XFCE)

How do I revert to the first behaviour ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that you might be right, @adempewolff. I tried of course beforehand to check if this question hasn't been asked before, but I missed this one. Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found someone having a similar problem on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/). And this problem was linked to the presence of an installation of the [XFCE desktop environment](http://www.xfce.org/).

Because it was also my case, I used a solution suggested in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1747534), which simply consists in erasing all traces of XFCE installation.

I opened a terminal and enter the following command :

```
sudo apt-get remove `dpkg -l | grep xfce|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Now, I can't use XFCE anymore but the normal behavior of the dash has been restored.

Comment: It is "only" xdg-utils, which is problematic, and can be fixed. See http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169.