# Text files open in Nautilus instead of Text Editor

Tags: nautilus, xdg-open

When I try to open a "plain text document" (no file extension) it opens its folder in the file manager (Nautilus), instead of opening the file in my text editor.

This happens when I open it through Chromium, or through the Dash, or through the command line using xdg-open.

I have set "Geany" as the default application to open "plain text document" with. But this only works if I open the file from within Nautilus.

Comment: If this happens for all files (also images etc), see http://askubuntu.com/a/493866/169.

Comment: Indeed removing exo-utils worked. Thanks.

Comment: Solution found on http://askubuntu.com/questions/35602/using-gnome-open-to-open-pdf-files/39602

Removing the exo-utils package worked.

Edit: "trivial answer converted to comment"... okay? If I can't answer my own question, then how do I go about marking this question as a duplicate then?

Comment: Please note that my answer explicitly mentions that you should not need to remove `exo-utils`, but that it can be fixed - just in case `exo-utils` is useful to you. I am adding a link to my answer as an answer. I have flagged it as duplicate.